# prolog non oriented graph, how find the number of persons between two persons?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I have to find the number of person between two persons (noeuds) with only one function.

I succeed for an oriented graph :

```
intermediaires(X,Y,N):-
   noeud(Index1,X),
   noeud(Index2,Y),
   lien(Index1,Index2),
   N is 0.
intermediaires(X,Y,N):-
   noeud(Index1,X),
   lien(Index1,IndexZ),
   noeud(IndexZ,Z),
   intermediaires(Z,Y,N1),
   N is N1 +1
```

but I don't understand how to do it for a non-oriented graph, do you have an idea ?

Comment: Maintain a list of already visited persons, and make sure that the new person you aim to visit is not in that list. If you visit a new person add that to the list.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how to do that because I can only use X,Y and N as argument in the function intermediaire(X,Y,N),  it's our teacher who decided that... X and Y are the names of the persones and N the number of the persons between.

Comment: Use a helper predicate.